# using response.Redirect(url) within a submit button

Tags: javascript, jsp, httprequest

I have the following problem:
I am writing a code that submit a form to `Target.jsp` and display a content within `Display.jsp` after the form is submitted to `Target.jsp`.

How  do I use `response.Redirect("jsp/Display")` within the following code?

```
   <form method="POST" class="example" action="/project/jsp/Target.jsp" id=form >
   <!--Some tags here-->


    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit Changes" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.location.href` for this.

```
window.location.href='/jsp/Display'
```

From client side JavaScript, this will navigate the browser to the new location.

However, evaluate if navigating to a new page is what you want? If you just need to display a piece of HTML returned after form submission, it might be wiser to use AJAX to capture that response and add it to the document tree, without navigating to different page.

Comment: my goal is to display that Display.jsp (html content) after a submit the form. how can I incorporate the window.location.href='' within the form tag or button code?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the information to Display.jsp from inside Target.jsp.

Comment: The issue is when I put action="/project/jsp/Display.jsp" it didn't fullfill my request.

Comment: No, action should be Target.jsp. When Target.jsp is processed, you can submit another form with target as Display.jsp.

Comment: <form method="POST" class="example" action="/project/jsp/Display.jsp" id=form3>